# What's the etymology of "las tantas"?

Tags: etimología, expresiones

What's the etymology of *las tantas* in the meaning of *very very late*?

[RAE dictionary](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Z60aNMi):

> **las tantas**
>
> *loc. sust. f. pl. coloq.* Una hora muy avanzada del día o de la noche.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably from "a las tantas" an abbreviation of "a las tantas horas" in this case.

This form is used to express when something is happening or happened at an **unknown/unexpected** late date or time and can be literally translated as "**at such hours"** or **"at the many"**,

ie:

> Spanish: **a las tantas** horas de la mañana llegó
>
> English: **at such**/**so many**  hours in the morning he arrived

I can't say there's an etymology related to the use, as this is used for the fact that the hours are counted and the more you get (las tantas), the later it is.